# How to squash several commits to another branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-squash

I will develop my app in branch `dev` and provide the "best so far" (a release on GitHub) on a branch `public`.

The branch `dev` will have commits `c964dea`, `06cf8ee`, `396b4a3` and `9be7fdb`. **I would like to squash them into a single commit on branch `public`** (leaving them as-it on the branch `dev`).

Is this possible?

I saw many questions and answers about squashing commits, but none of tehem seemed to address the problem of "squashing to another branch".

Comment: Conceptually, just squash into one commit- then cherry-pick the commit onto the target branch. Or cherry-pick the 4 commits to the target branch and then squash. There may be a one liner for this but I can't think of it at the moment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what you want: [Cherry-pick and squash a range of commits into a subdirectory or subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123108/cherry-pick-and-squash-a-range-of-commits-into-a-subdirectory-or-subtree)

Comment: @TTT well not exactly - I want to do that to another branch. Calum's answer is on spot (I need to test that with back-and-forth branches but I thnk it will be fine)

Comment: Yeah- The question I linked to is slightly different. I should have mentioned that the accepted answer is probably what you want. Basically if you use -n parameter with cherry-pick you can avoid the additional rebase afterwards. But if Calum's answer here is correct, then maybe `public` didn't exist yet. (I just assumed branch `public` already existed which is why cherry-pick with `-n` would be slightly faster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and switch to a new branch from `dev`.

```
git switch -c <new-branch>
```

It'll be identical to `dev` at this point but now you can squash the commits without changing `dev`. Start an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i <first-commit>
```

Then set all the commits to squash.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want first to cherry pick individual commits, if they are not in sequence by running :

```
git cherry-pick <commitSHA>
```

You will have a sequence of cherry-picked commits on your feature branch.
after that you want to do interactive rebase on your branch from all the commits you cherry-picked.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~<n+1>
```

where n is going to be the number of cherry-picked commits.
mark all the commits with **s** except the last one.
s, squash  = use commit, but meld into previous commit

if all your commits that you want to cherry-pick are in sequence, then it is easier :

```
git cherry-pick A^..B
```

where A and B are first and last commits to be cherry-picked. After that rebase them.